# P2os navigation stack

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, amcl, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi 
I'm using the navigation stack of the p2os package with Gazebo.
I'm launching *pioneer3dx.gazebo.launch* to simulate the p3dx robot.

```
<launch>

  <include file="$(find gazebo_worlds)/launch/office_world.launch"/>

  <include file="$(find p2os_urdf)/launch/upload_pioneer3dx.xml"/>

  <!-- push robot_description to factory and spawn robot in gazebo -->
  <node name="spawn_pioneer" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" 
    args="-z 0.051 
          -urdf 
          -param robot_description  
          -model robot_description" 
    respawn="false" output="screen" />

  <!-- Controller Manager -->
  <include file="$(find pr2_controller_manager)/controller_manager.launch" />

  <!-- load controllers -->
  <node name="diffdrive" pkg="gazebo_plugins" type="gazebo_ros_diffdrive" respawn="true" output="screen"/>


</launch>
```

Then I'm launching the *navigation.launch* file:

```
<launch>
    <master auto="start"/>
    
    <!-- Run the map server (you can run it here or in another terminal) -->
    <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find p2os_nav)/simple_office_map.png 0.1" respawn="true"/> 

    <!--- Run AMCL -->
    <include file="$(find p2os_launch)/amcl.launch" />
    
    <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
        <rosparam file="$(find p2os_launch)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="$(find p2os_launch)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="$(find p2os_launch)/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
        <rosparam file="$(find p2os_launch)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
        <rosparam file="$(find p2os_launch)/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
        <param name="base_global_planner" type="string" value="NavfnROS" />
        <param name="conservative_reset_dist" type="double" value="3.0" />
        <param name="controller_frequency" type="double" value="15.0" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

but I get this error:

```
[ WARN] [1358420453.650886449, 1103.836000000]: Waiting on transform from /base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error:
```

This transformation shouldn't be published by the navigation stack itself?
I should create a node which publish it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52553/p2os-navigation-stack/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-01-17**:
Does the Pioneer 3-DX model you use have a laser scanner? Is the tf between the laser scanner and /base_link being published? I have a feeling your problem might be related to amcl not being able to localize your robot because these are missing: http://ros.org/wiki/amcl#Transforms

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2013-01-17**:
I tried to publish a static tf between odom and map and now i get this warn: [ WARN] [1358422420.491334367, 44.120000000]: The scan observation buffer has not been updated for 32.25 seconds, and it should be updated every 0.20 seconds.
so you're right probably there is some problem with the laser

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-01-17**:
This might interest you: http://answers.ros.org/question/28171/transform-from-base_link-to-map/

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2013-01-17**:
Thank you so much george. Can you tell me how can I set properly the scan_topic in amcl?

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-01-17**:
What is the topic the simulated Hokuyo is publishing scans to? You have to remap that to the /scan topic in amcl.launch (or somewhere else).

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2013-01-17**:
Done and the error disappeared!Thx!If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll mark it as right :)

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2013-01-18**:
I have this problem now: http://answers.ros.org/question/52708/navigation-stack-problem/

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-01-18**:
Which part of it was actually the right answer? Was it remapping the /scan topic?

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2013-01-20**:
yes the fact that problem was in tha amcl file and that i have to remap the scan topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Run `rxgraph` to see what is going on: the Hokuyo laser needs to publish its scans to the same topic AMCL is listening. If needed, you can remap the `/scan` topic in `amcl.launch`. You may be interested in this [related question](http://answers.ros.org/question/28171/transform-from-base_link-to-map/).

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2013-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1